# regex: accepting but not capturing a pattern

Tags: regex

I want a pattern that matches on

```
ab
a-b
a b
a  b
a-b
```

where `a` and `b` can be any pattern, but are reduced to `a` and `b` for simplicity.

I want to return `"ab"` in all these cases. Can I do it all by regex or do I have to receive the matched expressions along with the separator characters and process them in code, by replacing the said characters and the like?

Comment: `I want to return "ab" in all these cases` What do you mean by _return_ ? There is no provision in any regex engine to skip inbetween stuff without matching/consuming it, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I'm using the said regex in a html form. I want the form to accept all the variation of `ab` but only submit `ab`. The question was if I could do it with regex only or if I needed to add some java script to achieve this.

Comment: No man, if you're submitting substrings at the time of validation it requires a couple of steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might misunderstood your meaning, if so I'm sorry about it.
You can group things in `regexp` with quotes `()`,
For example, with your case:

```
(a)(-|\s+)?(b)
```

And later use `\1` and `\3` to refer `a` and `b`. so `\1\3` would mean `ab`.
Note some tools may need to use `\\1\\3` instead.
Check the doc of your language to find out the exact regexp rules.

I'm not sure where will you use this, here I use `sed` as an example:

```
$ echo -e "ab\na-b\na b\na  b\n"|sed -E 's/^(a)(-| +)?(b)$/\1\3/'
ab
ab
ab
ab
```

Note the regex used here is `^(a)(-| +)?(b)$`, the `^` and `$` are to match the beginning and ending of a string/line.

In other words, those lines can be `accepted` by that regexp -- In some cases it's already validated.
But if you want to `return` `ab`, that's not simple matching but an addtional step of replace/reorganizing needed.

Comment: when you say "later on", do you mean manipulate the captured groups in code later? because trying your suggestion: https://regex101.com/r/5NmE51/1 returns `a-b` and `a b` for the "full match", which is presumably the text to be accessed directly. This is for validating a html form. I want to submit only 'ab' and not have to validate the posted data in my server code.

Comment: Guessing I can't do it in the regex then, right? if so, could you show me how I can concatenate it please?

Comment: thank you. to rephrase your response, it doesn't look like it's possible to combine the matched groups to create a "combo match". that bit has to be done as a post-process.